# How to share image on social Media in WP8.1 Rt?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have created app in wp8.1 rt. When button is clicked i need to take screen shot of page and share it on social media(like facebook,twiter ,...).
Upto now what i have done is -

```
DataTransferManager dtManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
   dtManager.DataRequested += dtManager_DataRequested;


private async void dtManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "here is title";
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "H..........";
        e.Request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("http://......."));
       //here i need to add image also
    }

private void share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
    }
```

Upto here its working ,i am able to share title, discription,.... but unable to share image that capture programatically
For capturing image what i have done is below:

```
 private async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CreateBitmapFromElement(FrameworkElement uielement)
    {
        try
        {
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

            return renderTargetBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

img.source= await CreateBitmapFromElement(rootcontent); //here rootcontent is my grid name that i need to capture.

Here i am able to get imge also. But unable to share this captured image.
I read some blogs but still unable to solve it.
I think i need to convert it to BitmapImage. How can i do that?? Or is there another best way of handling this problem.

what I need is when share button is clicked ,i need to capture screenshot and  share it on social media (like facebook).

- Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.Request.Data.SetBitmap to transfer a screen shot. But the parameter type of this method is RandomAccessStreamReference, so you need to convert the RenderTargetBitmap to RandomAccessStreamReference.

The essential idea is: Get the pixels and write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

You can find the code reference from article [How to use the RenderTargetBitmap in Windows 8.1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey Chen ,i did everything  same  as in article but still unable to share captured image. I have added only button click event in article code.  Is here something wrong ,,                                                                                                        private void Share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
        }

Comment: @Jayanta, besides setting the sharing source correctly, the share target also need to support receiving the bitmap content. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741262.aspx#check_to_see_if_the_datapackageview_contains_a_bitmap

Comment: thanks @Jeffrey Chen, I am  still unable to solve the problem i modified in package.appxmanifest as in article. But did not understand  other things. Can you please provide me codes that i need to add here.